# How to use a continuous function on $[0,1]$ to prove another set is connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, path-connected

Given $[0,1] \in \mathbb{R}$ and $E$ a metric space, $f:[0,1] \to E$. How to prove $E$ is connected? Is it to prove that $f([0,1]) =E$?

I come up with this idea because my text uses a continuous function on $[0,1]$ to prove all ball in Euclidean space, and Euclidean space itself, are connected after introducing intermediate value theorem. I also read the Wikipedia, but there are some concepts that I don't have a good understanding yet. Such as path, curve, path connectedness, arc connectedness.

Also, what're the differences between path connectedness and arc connectedness?

[image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space]
[image]

Comment: If $f$ is continuous, then its image is connected (and compact) since $[0,1]$ is.  However, $f$ doesn't need to be surjective, so $E$ doesn't need to be connected.

Comment: Path-connectedness is stronger than connectedness. Any space that is path-connected is connected, but the converse is not true.

Comment: $\Bbb{R}^2\Bbb{Q}^2$ is path connected. Is it also connected?

Comment: Thank you all for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you can prove that there exists a continuous function $f : [0,1] \rightarrow E$ which is onto, then, since, the continuous image of a connected subset is connected, $E$ is connected as well.

$[0,1]$ being an interval in $\mathbb R$ is connected.

Comment: Closedness has nothing to do with connectedness: consider two distinct points

Comment: Yep, I corrected it. Thanks for pointing